# Swagger WebApi create json on build

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

Is there any way to create the swagger json during the build task of my web api? I want to use the json to feed it into a code generator and generate a typescript definition file.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: NSwag generates Swagger spec for a Web API controller: https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to create (and combine) the jsons for all Controllers at once via the command line tool?

Comment: You want to combine multiple controllers into one Swagger spec? (= or combine multiple specs into one?)

Comment: I have multiple Controllers in my WebAPI. I don't want to create a Swagger-Spec file for each one of them. I want to make one single NSwag call and create a single Spec without specifying which Controllers are in the WebAPI (NSwag should automatically detect them)

Comment: This should be easy, give me some days... i'll close the following issue as soon as its implemented: https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/issues/7

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [NSwag](http://nswag.org) command line tools like this:

```
nswag.exe webapi2swagger /assembly:"path/to/assembly.dll" /output:"path/to/swagger.json"
```

This generates a Swagger specification with for all controllers in the given DLL.

For more information [read this page](https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/wiki/CommandLine).

Comment: Hi Rico, thanks for making this feature available! One question though: Why does NSwag (or Swagger by itself) thow an InvalidOperationException when I want to use an object or array as an URI-Parameter?

Comment: This must be a bug in the NSwag implementation. Can you post a sample Web API controller which causes the exception?

Comment: And can you post the exception message you get?

Comment: If I have something like this:
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("xyz/{data}")]
        public string Xyz(MyClass data)
        {
            return "abc";
        }

I get a System.InvalidOperationException:
The parameter 'data' cannot be an object or data.

You seem to activelly deny the data-Parameter. To clearify: I've created a ModelBinder for the MyClass so it can be parsed from a string and vice versa.

Comment: Ok, but this is an actual runtime error when calling the service, not an exception from the NSwag tools?

Comment: No, as I said it's an exception that gets fired by NSwag. If I call the service it runs just smoothly (of course it can only run because of the ModelBinder)

Comment: The problem is in the CreatePrimitiveParameter method of the WebApiToSwaggerGenerator class. There you check for objects and arrays and make them "unparsable"

Comment: Ah yes, I see... Currently only simple objects are allowed as non-body param... But i can disable this rule to support custom model binders.. Didnt think of this scenario

Comment: is the parameter "MyClass data" a body or query parameter? If its a query parameter, how can I detect that it is query and not body?

Comment: ... or is the MyClass class marked with an ModelBinder attribute?

Comment: It's a query parameter. This could be detected from the route. But it wouldn't hurt me if I had to append an [FromUri] attribute to the parameter.

Comment: Ah, this is another case... in your case, the type of the "path" parameter in the swagger spec is a string... correct?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the tools, please try again (v0.19.5784.33424)... If there are any other problems, please open an issue on GitHub...

Comment: That's correct. Actually every path parameter can be interpreted as a string due to the fact that the path itself is a string. The ModelBinder parses that string into an instance of the specified class.

Answer (score 19):

I'm using **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli** (note: I'm using .NET Core 3.1)
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Add the following packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc5" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="5.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.3.1" />
```

Next, create a tool manifest:

```sh
dotnet new tool-manifest
```

Install the Swashbuckle CLI tool and add it to the local manifest file:

```sh
dotnet tool install --version 5.3.1 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
```

Now you can use a dotnet command to generate a swagger.json file. For example:

```sh
dotnet swagger tofile --output api.json bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1/xxx.yourApi.dll v1
```

If you want the file to be generated on each build, use a PostBuild target in your csproj file.

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json $(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll v1 " />
</Target>
```

Comment: I met the error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.1.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli 6.1.3 supports:
  - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) / any
  - netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any
  - netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) / any

Comment: This looks like a nice way to go, but dotnet 5.0 doesn't seem to be supported: `It was not possible to find any compatible framework version. The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.9 `

Comment: Alright! It actually works with version `6.1.5`

Comment: @MarkWalsh this DOES work with .NET 6. Make sure you use the right version of the tool.  6.4.0 indeed.

Comment: It does indeed @Enrico but only if you’re not doing things like configuring external dependencies on things like KeyVault etc as the generation may fail.  You can mitigate that by passing environment variables and only conditionally invoking them

Comment: That has nothing to do with the tool. Depends on how you set-up your .NET solution.

Comment: @Enrico Yep...that's what I said - I've even deleted my original comment!