# Generate Swagger json at Build time

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-devops, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core WebAPI project and I'm trying to find a way to generate swagger json at build time ?

As i'm working with 4 environments, i'd like to have 4 swagger.json with a different name of my choice, like:

- swagger_{appName}*dev*{buildNumber}.json
- swagger_{appName}*demo*{buildNumber}.json
- swagger_{appName}*int*{buildNumber}.json
- swagger_{appName}*staging*{buildNumber}.json

Is it also possible to edit the fields in the json ? I'd like to edit (depending of the environment) the following fields : host, schemes and basePath.

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore but it appears it doesn't have an option to do such task or am I wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Potential duplicate that specifically answers the OP.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283071/swagger-webapi-create-json-on-build

Answer (score 10):

You have the option of generating OpenApi json file(s) from the command line without deploying using the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli` nuget package.

The command will look something like this and can be added as a "post build" script

```
dotnet <nugetpackages>\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp<ver>\dotnet-swagger.dll tofile --host http://localhost --output swagger.json <bin>\<AssemblyName>.dll v1
```

more details can be found here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli

I'm not sure about generating separate files for each environment offhand

Comment: @StepDo any suggestions if I need to generate all the versions ? If I skip V1 it fails

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a good article](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2022/09/aspnet-coregenerate-your-swaggerjson-at.html) about generating `swagger.json` file at build-time.

Here is the summary

1. In the root folder of your project execute the following command

   ```
   dotnet new tool-manifest
   ```
2. Then execute the following command

   ```
   dotnet tool install SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.Cli
   ```
3. Add the following snippet to your .csproj file of Web Project (the project that contains swagger NuGet packages)

   ```
   <Target Name="CreateSwaggerJson" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
      <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ./PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT/swagger.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
   </Target>
   ```

replace the `PATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT` with the path you want (use already existing folders, this script does not create folders if not exist)

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is using **PowerShell** task to update json file and save with another name.

Simple workflow:

1. Read the file through [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) script
2. Using [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) to converts content to object
3. Set the property value to update object
4. Using [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) to convert an object to a JSON-formatted string
5. Using [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) to write content to a file

For detail code, you can refer to this thread: [how do I update json file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865272/how-do-i-update-json-file-using-powershell).

The build number value is stored in the predefined variable: `Build.BuildNumber` (PowerShell: `$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`)

Comment: I'll take a look at this ;) But the first step is to read the json file, how shall I read it if it's not present in the artifact ? (when building the project, there's a .dll, .deps.json, .pdb, .runtimeconfig.json and .runtimeconfig.dev.json but no sign of a swagger.json inside)

Comment: How do you generate the swagger.json in local machine?

Comment: I go to to URL (when running) : localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: Run the core app through PowerShell task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878032/powershell-not-returning-to-command-line-after-running-dotnet-run, then call the API to generate swagger.json. (You can call start-sleep PS script wait some seconds)